# Code not displaying output properly

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm new to C and wrote a code where I would like to display "?" on the screen where it matches the value in an array. If I have an array initialized with index_location[6] = {0, 1, 5, 8, 9, 12}; my expected output is detailed below. Any help or assistance in helping me is greatly appreciated.

> Output:
>   ??@@@?@@??@@?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//
int main(void)
{
    int index_location[6] = {0, 1, 5, 8, 9, 12};
    int len=sizeof(index_location)/sizeof(int);

    for (int a = 0; a < len; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < len; b++)
        {
            if ( a == index_location[b])
            {
                printf("%c",'?'); 
            } else {
                printf("%c",'@'); 
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You should really show what you actually get.  I suspect it is a lot more data than your expected output.  Are you sure the double loop is needed?  You should be using a single loop, I think.  In C, you need to use `for (int a = 0; a < len; a++)` as the idiomatic loop; with `<=` rather than `<` you access a non-existent element of the array, which leads to 'undefined behaviour', which is to be avoided at all costs (because anything can happen when you invoke undefined behaviour, and anything that happens is 'correct' behaviour).

Comment: Should it not be printf('?') according to your requiermets

Comment: Array boundaries are off `for (a=0; a<len; ++a)`. Also, you really shouldn't specify both a size and an initializer for index_location: `int index_location[]=...` would be better.

Comment: Ok, now you have changed the code on us making all the comments irrelevent. But still haven't told us what the actual behaviour of your program is. And even your requirements are not clear: "where it matches the value in an array". What is *it* and what is *it* matching with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a single loop.  You need to go through index positions 0..12 inclusive (where 12 is the last entry in the `index_location` array), checking whether you need to print a `?` or `@` each time.  When you've printed the character corresponding to one of the `index_location` entries, you need to move on to looking at the next one.  You could add a liberal collection of `assert()` invocations to ensure that things are under control, but as long as the array is in sorted order, you should be OK (and you might get away with it even if it's not, though you might miss some requested `?` marks).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int index_location[6] = {0, 1, 5, 8, 9, 12};
    int len = sizeof(index_location) / sizeof(index_location[0]);
    int max = index_location[len - 1];
    int idx = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a <= max; a++)
    {
        if (a < index_location[idx])
            putchar('@');
        else
        {
            putchar('?');
            idx++;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
??@@@?@@??@@?
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in your for loops. I would go with the below solution.
If the array index_location[] is sorted in ascending order, use this for loop with double initialization intead:

```
int max = index_location[len-1];
for(int i = 0,j = 0; i <= max; i++)
{
    if ( i == index_location[j])
    {
       printf("%c",'?');
       j++;
    } 
    else {
       printf("%c",'@');
    }
}
```